# Proving $\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x+ 1/2}{x - 1} = \frac{7}{4}$ with $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: limits

My unfinished solution:

> By the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\Big{|}\dfrac{x + 1/2}{x - 1} - \dfrac{7}{4}\Big{|} < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x - 3| < \delta$.
>
> We know that:
>
> $$\begin{array}{rcl}
> \Big{|}\dfrac{x + 1/2}{x - 1} - \dfrac{7}{4}\Big{|} &=& \Big{|}\dfrac{2x + 1}{2x - 2} - \dfrac{7}{4}\Big{|}\\
> &=&\dfrac{3}{4}\cdot\dfrac{|x  - 3|}{|x - 1|}\\
> &<&\dfrac{3}{4}\cdot \dfrac{\delta}{|x - 1|}
> \end{array}$$

I am quite confused and I don't know what I am doing actually. Can anyone tell me how to continue?

Comment: I think you want to write $<\epsilon$ and $<\delta$ in your definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now you need to bound $|x-1|$ from below so you can write another inequality that does not involve $x$.  The usual way, which works here, is to pick a preliminary range for $\delta$.  It doesn't matter much what you use.  We could say $\delta \lt \frac 12$.  Then $x \in (\frac 52, \frac 72)$ and $|x-1| \gt \frac 32$.  Then you can say
$$\frac 34\cdot \frac \delta{|x-1|} \lt \frac 34 \cdot\frac \delta{\frac 32}=\frac 12\delta$$
If we keep this smaller than $\epsilon$ we will satisfy the demand, so our answer is $$ \delta \lt \min(\frac 12, \frac 12\epsilon)$$
will guarantee that $$\left|\frac{x+\frac 12}{x-1}-\frac 74\right| \lt \epsilon$$

Comment: @Max Wong:  I found a typo that did not change the strategy.  I had $\frac 23$ instead of $\frac 32.$